# Starting ColorBox slideshow using a link

Tags: jquery-plugins, colorbox

I would like to have a page with both an image gallery and a slideshow. The slideshow should be started when I click the link, the normal ColorBox should be used when I click one of the images.

What I do now is group all the images with a rel. For the slideshow link I use the following code:

```
<a rel="slideshow" href="#">Display slideshow</a>
```

In the configuration for colorbox I define rel as the rel I use for the images. This works almost, the problem I have with this is that I get an extra empty page at the beginning.

How can I start a slideshow of an image gallery, using a text link?

Answer (score 5):

I searched for how to do this for a long time, and finally found the answer on - where else - the F.A.Q for Colorbox.  The example is worded a bit differently though so it wasn't as easy to find as you might think.  Especially if you're asking question in these terms, like I was.

```
<div style="display:none;"> <!-- optionally hide this div -->
    <a rel="gallery" href="/slideshow/one.jpg">Caption 1</a>
    <a rel="gallery" href="/slideshow/two.jpg">Caption 2</a>
    <a rel="gallery" href="/slideshow/three.jpg">Caption 3</a>
</div>
<a id="openGallery" href="#">Display slideshow</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
var $gallery = $("a[rel=gallery]").colorbox();
$("a#openGallery").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $gallery.eq(0).click();
});
</script>
```

http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq/#faq-click

Comment: @Julesfrog Since you've edited this question, I'm going to vote to delete your answer as it now duplicates this one (and Jody has had plenty of time to roll back your edit if needed).

Comment: Whatever works is fine.  The code you changed makes sense, but as far as I can tell, the code I had from before [did work](http://jsfiddle.net/sg5zqb7c/), and it's copied verbatim from the ColorBox FAQ.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jody!