# Run slideshow from hyperlink using Jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, colorbox, magnific-popup

```
 <div class="image-container" style="display:none;"> 
                    <a  href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?> /images/events/Caroline Springs 29112013/1.jpg">Caption 1</a>
                    <a  href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?> /images/events/Caroline Springs 29112013/2.jpg">Caption 2</a>
                    <a  href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?> /images/events/Caroline Springs 29112013/3.jpg">Caption 3</a>
                    <a  href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?> /images/events/Caroline Springs 29112013/4.jpg">Caption 4</a>
                    <a  href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?> /images/events/Caroline Springs 29112013/5.jpg">Caption 5</a>
                    <a  href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?> /images/events/Caroline Springs 29112013/6.jpg">Caption 6</a>
            </div> 
<a id="openGallery" href="#">Caroline Springs</a>
```

I am trying to create a slideshow on the fly where in when the user clicks on the Caroline Springs link, the slide show starts. As it was already discussed in this thread :[Starting ColorBox slideshow using a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282401/starting-colorbox-slideshow-using-a-text-link)  I tried to replicate it but its not working for me. Than I tried using the magnicfic popup (link http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) but still the same result. my jquery looks like this:

```
$(".events .previous-events .container-list-row1 a#openGallery").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();


    $('.image-container').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a', // child items selector, by clicking on it popup will open
    type: 'image'
    // other options
    });

});
```

Please have a look and let me know how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was with jquery conflict for which I have submitted another question on stack overflow